# Is there a "health check" endpoint for Grafana running in a Docker container?

Tags: docker, grafana, aws-fargate

I am setting up Grafana in Fargate using Docker. Once the Grafana container is active, is there an endpoint I can call that Fargate could use to determine if the container is "healthy" or not?

For example: http://grafana/healthy or http://grafana/status

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Returns health information about Grafana

> GET /api/health

It is documented: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/http_api/other/#returns-health-information-about-grafana

Or undocumented (so use it only if you understand how it works and what are consequences):

> GET /healthz

https://github.com/grafana/grafana/pull/27536

Comment: Thanks again Jan.